# Currency Converter Visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net

I'm here for a bit problem in dealing the currency conversion by manual.

How to put another value on the same existed combobox which the answers must be different.

Example Japan Yen to US Dollars = 12.43 but US Dollars to Japan Yen does have same answer.

What is the way to put the values on combobox2 which the answers are always different when set.

---

```
 Private Sub CurrencyFromCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CurrencyFromCombobox.SelectedIndexChanged


 Select Case CurrencyFromCombobox.Text

 Case "Japanese Yen - JPY"
            fromjapan = 1
        Case "U.S. Dollar - USD"
            fromUSdollars = 1
    End Select


 Private Sub CurrencyToCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CurrencyToCombobox.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case CurrencyToCombobox.Text
        Case "Japanese YEN - JPY"
            japanto = 1.0
            USto = 323
        Case "Euro - EUR"
            japanto = 0.0075774548
        Case "British Pound - GBP"
            japanto = 0.0064142153
        Case "Indian Rupee - INR"
            japanto = 0.6309714918
        Case "Australian Dollar - AUD"
            japanto = 0.0108982954
        Case "U.S. Dollar - USD"
            japanto = 0.0102789194
        Case "Canadian Dollar - CAD"
            japanto = 0.010583474
        Case "UAE Dirham - AED"
            japanto = 0.0377534428

    End Select


    '------------------------------------------------------------Currency rates ffom US        Dollars
    Select Case CurrencyToCombobox.Text
        Case "Japanese YEN - JPY"
            USto = 323
        Case "Euro - EUR"
            USto = 0.7368
        Case "British Pound - GBP"
            USto = 0.6217
    End Select
End Sub

   Private Sub Enterbutton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Enterbutton.Click
    Dim enter As Decimal

    ' Japanese yen conversion
    enter = Val(Enteramounttxt.Text)
    result = enter * fromjapan * japanto
    Resulttxt.Text = result.ToString

    ' US Dollar conversion

    result1 = enter * fromUSdollars * USto
    Resulttxt.Text = result1.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not a good project because currencies will always change. Best would be to connect to Google's Currency Converter API which always has the latest updated currency values.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (requires internet connection to work)

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox(Convert(0.5, "USD", "EUR"))
    End Sub

    Public Function Convert(ByVal amount As Decimal, ByVal fromCurrency As String, ByVal toCurrency As String) As Decimal

        Dim web As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
        Dim url As String = String.Format("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q={2}{0}%3D%3F{1}", fromCurrency.ToUpper(), toCurrency.ToUpper(), amount)
        Dim response As String = web.DownloadString(url)

        Dim regex As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("rhs: \""(\d*.\d*\.?\d*)")
        Dim match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = regex.Match(response)

        Dim rate As Decimal = System.Convert.ToDecimal(match.Groups(1).Value)
        Return rate
    End Function
End Class
```